# Android: Autocompletetextview dropdown hides after entering space

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have created an `AutoCompleteTextView` drop-down which contains multiple words in a row like -

```
row 1 - Infosys Limited
row 2 - State Bank of India
```

when I'm entering Infosys, it works fine when I enter space after the drop-down goes off.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, GreenDaoUtils.getSSSymbolNamesArray(this));
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
autoCompleteTextView.setLines(8);
autoCompleteTextView.setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cust_rect_border));
autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **FilterWithSpaceAdapter** instead of ArrayAdapter

u get from [FilterWithSpaceAdapter here](https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/blob/master/src/com/luksprog/playground/adapter/FilterWithSpaceAdapter.java)

```
  FilterWithSpaceAdapter<String> adapter1;
  adapter1 = new FilterWithSpaceAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, GreenDaoUtils.getSSSymbolNamesArray(this));
```

Comment: `FilterWithSpaceAdapter` there is no such thing in the SDK

Comment: get from https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/blob/master/src/com/luksprog/playground/adapter/FilterWithSpaceAdapter.java

Comment: so write it in your answer